# Imprimir respuesta en un archivo (cualquier formato) nuevo [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Quiero que la respuesta de X ejecución se imprima en un archivo creado según mis especificaciones (formato, carpeta).

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Podrías explicar con seudocódigo lo que quieres hacer. En node lo que dices podría referirse a un código ejecutado por consola (en cuyo caso ocuparías el operador > por ejemplo) o a la escritura de un archivo internamente usando `fs.createFile`.